# How to trigger Cucumber parallel test execution using TestNG and tags via command line?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber

I need to be able to trigger my Cucumber tests via command line, currently I'm using Cucumber 4 and I have read the following documentation: https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/

My problem: when running the command listed below it seems to execute all my tests instead of only running the Login tests.

I'm expecting to run a command via command line, which targets my testng.xml which in turn targets my runner however providing me the option to alter test tags and thread count via command line.

Thanks

Examples:

Doesn't work:
`mvn clean compile test -Denvironment=test4 -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/features --glue stepDefinitions --tags @Login--plugin pretty --plugin html:target/cucumber --plugin json:target/cucumber.json --threads 3"`

Doesn't work:
`mvn clean compile test -Denvironment=test4 -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/features --glue stepDefinitions --tags @Login--plugin pretty --plugin html:target/cucumber --plugin json:target/cucumber.json --threads 3 -g parallel src/test/features"`

Works but triggers all tests instead of just Login tests:
`mvn clean compile test -Ddataproviderthreadcount=2 -Dcucumber.options="--tags @login"`

My Runner Class (Uses Tesng):

```
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

@CucumberOptions(features = { "classpath:features" }, glue = {
        "stepDefinitions"}, monochrome = true, tags = {"@login"}, dryRun = false,
        plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json"})

public class MainRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}

//TestNG xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes">
    <!--   <test  name="Test" parallel="methods" thread-count="3"> -->
    <!--    <test name="Test">-->
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="runners.MainRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```